# Rotating a log file in my home directory on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

Tags: log, logging

I have a log file `ircd.log` in `/home/irc`.

I want to rotate it daily at 00:00 and keep 7 days.

I want the rotated log files to be saved as `ircd.log.YYYYMMDD` for example `ircd.log.20140505`.

Can someone please tell me the package to use and also an example configuration for it based on this? Also is it possible to store this configuration at the user level?

Answer (score 7):

As @bain mentioned, the package is called `logrotate`.  To rotate this file as you have mentioned, you could use the following configuration in `/etc/logrotate.d/irc`:

```
/home/irc/ircd.log {
    daily
    rotate 7
    compress
    missingok
    create 0644 irc irc
    su irc irc
}
```

A breakdown of the configuration options:

- The `daily` option tells `logrotate` to process this file every day when it is run.
- The `rotate 7` option tells it to keep 7 copies.
- The `compress` option tells it to `gzip` the old files.
- `missingok` tells `logrotate` not to complain if it is missing.
- `create` tells the mode, owner, and group to use when creating files.
- `su` changes the user who runs the compression, etc, so you may not want to include it

Comment: I was planning to set up logrotate for some script logs in my home folder as well. This is unrelated to the question but do you by any chance know if the compressed archives retain user permissions (seeing how logrotate is executed with root permissions)?

Comment: I've edited my post to include the `su` option, which I believe is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

The package you want is called "logrotate". The [man page](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) has examples, and if you search you will find many tutorials on the web.